# Why does my len() code in python not provide the correct length of a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a hangman game using python and I'm having issues getting the correct length of a string to return when I run the code.  It will return things like `['clouds'] 10` or `['mango'] 9` or `['rose'] 8` when it should actually be returning `['clouds'] 6` and `['mango'] 5` and `['rose'] 4`.

Please help me see what I'm doing wrong!

Here's what I wrote:

```
import random

word_list = ['tiger','dog','cake','disney','donut','rose','clouds','movies','sparkle','yoga','walrus','candle','mango','taco','flowers']

word = str(random.sample(word_list, 1))

word_len = len(word)

print(word, word_len)
```

Comment: `sample` returns a *list*, which you turn into a string. The `['']` are part of your value and are counted towards its length. Try `choice` instead of `sample`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.sample(word_list, 1)` returns single item `list` like ["sparkle"] and you're converting it into `str` so it adds `[""]` around the word so word becomes `'["sparkle"]'`

I think you need:

```
import random

word_list = ['tiger','dog','cake','disney','donut','rose','clouds','movies','sparkle','yoga','walrus','candle','mango','taco','flowers']

word = random.sample(word_list, 1)
word_len = len(word[0])

print(word, word_len)
```

Output:

```
['sparkle'] 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using wrong method

```
import random

word_list = ['tiger','dog','cake','disney','donut','rose','clouds','movies','sparkle','yoga','walrus','candle','mango','taco','flowers']
# return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set
# where k is 1, population sequence is word_list
print(random.sample(word_list, 1))

# to get random item from list you have to use random.choice
print(random.choice(word_list))
```

Comment: But he needs list of value,  choice returns random value only.

Comment: @SaisivaA where did you find it? As I can see from question OP had a problem with len, but there is no word about what OP needs, I mean list or just one random item from it